# android Copy protection Forward-locking - should I not bother?

Tags: android, android-lvl, copy-protection

Should i abandon Copy protection for my android apps?  It will be deprecated soon and I recently noticed that some devices will not show these apps due to this copy protection. Generally, with the SDK you can easily extract these apks anyway, so anyone with any knowledge can bypass this 'security'.

I really dont want to implement this new security protocol as it looks like it could cause problems for the user accessing apps without a connection.  Generally it looks too complicated.  Is anyone using this new copy protection?

My apps don't have many downloads so this is not super important, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Should i abandon Copy protection for my android apps?

If you are referring to the "copy protection" checkbox on the Android Market, you most definitely should not use it. As you note, it is pointless and may cause problems, plus it is being phased out.

> I really dont want to implement this new security protocol as it looks like it could cause problems for the user accessing apps without a connection.

While you can set up policies to try to reduce this, in the end, LVL does assume at least occasional connections back to Google for license verification.

I would recommend you not worry about copy protection, and instead focus on business models that do not require you to be paid directly by individuals for apps.

Answer (score -1):

If you have already opt-ed into this option and then disable it, wont current users be required to uninstall the application ultimately losing all their data?

Providing a data backup feature is ideal but assuming they are doing so isn't reliable.